# Which model here is more stable and why do you say so?

Tags: model-selection, scikit-learn

I have 2 models to choose from. The first model seems to be well-performing, no overfitting, and it (testing set) reaches the optimal performance with lesser number of samples as compared to the second model.

On the other hand, the zigzag training set line seems to be disturbing. Can I interpret that this model is unstable?

Although the second model takes more number of samples to reach its optimal performance, it's relatively more "smooth" and appears to be more stable than the first model.

Which one would you choose? And why?

**UPDATED with suggested changes**

But on a side note, putting the Y-axis on a scale of 0 to 1 makes it hard to interpret and the zig-zag effect isn't so obvious. Need help on that.

[image: Model A-Put Y axis on a scale of 0 to 1 and labelled]
[image: Model B-Put Y axis on a scale of 0 to 1 and labelled]

Comment: You should repost the two images but with the same y-axis scale, preferably from 0.00-1.00.

Comment: It would really help if you labeled you axies and charts.  As of now there are two pictures of a red dotted and a blue solid curve.

Comment: Still kind of hard to interpret, I'm not sure what "Number of samples" means, but, otherwise, they look about the same. The zig-zag stuff I would interpret as random. I think that if you reran the same training on the same data you would get yet a different looking graph. There is a good about of randomness in these things and only the final result is important.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I'm actually using the "learning_curve" function from sci kit learn to plot this. An example from them is here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/learning_curve.html

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree with @user1367204. Such small differences may well be due to pure chance. The only thing that gets me slightly worried is the positive trend of test set accuracy for the second model, but again, that could be purely random. If you want to be extra sure, try different random splits or (better) use cross-validation, but overall the two models look equally inaccurate to me.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply! Does that means that test set accuracy shouldn't be higher than training set in any circumstances?

Comment: Can you give an example or explanation of what "number of samples" means?

Comment: the model is actually being repeatedly trained with an incremental number of samples, and in the process, the accuracy score is measured.